# Revert accidental uninstall of Windows

Tags: uninstall, data-recovery

I followed some instructions to uninstall Ubuntu on my HDD because I would like to reinstall Ubuntu on an external HDD.

I burned the image on a dvd. Unfortunately when starting the computer with the DVD, Windows was was completely uninstalled (I was trying to uninstall Ubuntu).

Therefore is it possible to go back and restore windows?

Comment: Of course I am asking from a previous Dell computer.

Comment: Maybe you deleted the windows partition using the live DVD.

Comment: Are you able to boot into Ubuntu on your computer, or is neither Ubuntu or Windows booting up?

Comment: Looks like you was using Ubuntu loader (grub), and when you uninstalling Linux you have uninstalled Grub.

Comment: If you boot into the live DVD again and open gParted what can you see. What partitions are there?